# DynamicCacheLayerManager.Connect deletes my tiles

Tags: arcgis-engine

You are supposed to be able to connect to your existing tiles with this command.

```
dynamicCacheLayerManager.Connect(tileCacheDir, tileCachePath);
```

When I do that my tiles are destroyed and rebuilt.  Clearly this isn't the desired behavior, does anyone have any tips?

I'm using ArcEngine 10 in C# with VS2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my tiles were generated using a different Spatial Projection than my map.  Also I needed to connect to a target cache and then save the layer again, somewhere in the layer file it points to the cache.  Once that's complete, then all you have to do is load the layer, and the cache will be connected to automatically without any need to use the DynamicCacheLayerManager.